# How can I read which character is present at certain console position?

Tags: c#, .net, console

In the space-invaders game in console, how can I code the event where the bullet hits the enemy. For this may be I need to read which character is in a certain console position. If the character is the enemy's character then it will be marked as kill. But I don't know how can I read the what character is in a console position? Is there some function like ReadCharInConsole(positionX, positionY) in .Net/C#?

Comment: The space-invaders is being shown as a matrix I presume? Then I see no problem in getting the x/y of it. Add code examples

Comment: Instead of relying what's on the screen, store the position of the enemy in an array / matrix and then see if that position is currently occupied.

Answer (score 1):

Reading directly from console can be difficult however a solution would be storing the game state in a 2d array and reading directly from there.